# How to echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] when using selectbox

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error when echo $_GET[“jsoncallback”]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134415/error-when-echo-getjsoncallback)

```
<select name="test">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

When I

```
echo  $_GET["jsoncallback"] . '('<select name="test"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>')';
```

result error `invalid XML attribute value` . How to fix it?

Comment: Same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134415/error-when-echo-getjsoncallback/8134467#8134467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad PHP. try this:

```
echo  $_GET["jsoncallback"].'(<select name="test"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your quotes

```
 '('<sele
 ^ ^^
 | || 
 | | -Nonsense XML
 |  --End of string
  ----Start of string
```

You have the same problem at the end. Get rid of the extra single quote characters.

… and JSON-P should use **JSON**. The outermost object must be an Object or an Array, not a String.